# CVCS for people who use DVCS

Tags: git, version-control

I normally use Git for my projects at school and other personal projects. For an internship, we have to use an internal source control system that's very centralized (it seems to be very similar to the workflow of subversion from what I've been reading). However, having never used a centralized VCS, I don't really quite know the best workflow for that. How will using a centralized VCS affect my workflow and what are the best practices for using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be slower (because all operations are distant) and everything you'll commit will be available to everybody immediately (as soon as they update), but you probably won't find so many problems.

You'll probably have to abandon the idea of using branchs, so be prepared to use configurations or small hacks (env variables) instead. Try not to rename or move files, as this is generally costly and breaks history in old versionning systems.

Don't be afraid : it's slower, less powerful, but also simpler and easier. And you can use git locally if you want as you just have to exclude the ".git" directory from commits (and, if possible, only commit while in your `master` branch).

Just check it's not a super old system in which you have to centrally lock files (take ownership) before you can change them.

Comment: -1 for "abandon branches". I understand merging quality differs for DVCS and CVCS, but e.g. on Subversion branches still provide much more benefits than overhead and can be successfully used (personal experience + people around me).

Comment: We don't know if it's subversion. Hence the "probably". And Subversion is well know for its problems and slownesses with branches on real big projects.

Comment: My point is not about idealness of Subversion branching/merging. But about benefits being clearly bigger than overhead (experienced this with hundred libraries, thousands files, dozens of developers). Even in TFS (which I'm kind of "anti-fan" of)branchless development is much worse.

Answer (score 0):

Just use git locally, and consolidate changes when required for the Big Push you'll need when the big CM system kicks in. If needed pretend it's a funny sort of zip file technique ;-)

Most big company centralised CM systems (with mixed engineering disciplines) are still based on Drawing office practices from the time of the Titanic, when the master drawings were on kaolin & linen, and drawn in india ink. They had to be very well protected from any possibility of damage - no drawing, no ship, hence all the processes you probably see.

DVCS (such as git) is a response to the destruction of that concern - duplicating the master is now a zero cost activity in the software community, especially as the sha1 provides ease of verification that you have the correct copy. It will take many decades for the big systems to even slightly release their grasp of the levers of power....